# Why do flags age away?

Tags: support, flags

Why do flags age away?

[image: flags age away]

What do the words "no one" refer to? Who handle flags? Is it moderators?

How much "time" is "allowed by the system"?

Comment: The [question in question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183841/wi-fi-issue-with-ubuntu-19-10) has four close votes as I type this, so it will probably get closed, despite your flag aging away. As a side note, it is our policy not to flag or vote to close questions as EOL when the version they are asking about was not EOL at the time of posting. 19.10 was still warm from the oven back then. The question is now getting closed as unclear (probably because of the lack of any meaningful text in it, although the comments seem to add helpful info).

Answer (score 7):

In this case, a flag to close a question, it's handled by users with 3,000 or more reputation in the [Close Votes review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/stats). It's quite full, 170 questions (though nowhere near Stack Overflow levels) and that means that for some questions the review never gets completed. Even though there may be enough active reviewers, if the decision to close a question or leave it open is difficult, some of them may skip the review.

Close votes and close flags age away after [4-14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/295232) - if you're certain the question should be closed, you can flag again. Otherwise, it's better to leave it open; the worst thing that can happen is that it gets an answer :)

Comment: In my case, the flag aged away before 14 days. Why so?

Comment: Huh, that's weird, that should not happen. Might be worth adding this information to your question and add the [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: I was searching about flags aging away and I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). It's mentioned in the website: "Finally, flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away: rude/abusive and spam flags expire after 48 hours (and are removed immediately if the post is rolled back to a revision prior to the one which was flagged); close flags expire after between 4-14 days (depending on other votes and views)."

Comment: @technastic_tc thanks! I've also found a better reference - apparently I based my answer on an old situation.